# What to do when a struct ends up becoming a constraint (due to interfaces - and the compiler goes grumpy)?

Tags: c#, generics, struct, interface, constraints

**EDIT:**
*I have come to the conclusion that it's impossible to meet all my desired requirements!*

**Original Question...**
I appear to have run into an unfortunate dilemma. It boils down to the fact that structs are not valid generic constraints - which is perfectly sane, but a problem arises non the less...

Why would you *ever* want to constrain generics to a struct??
Well I don't *really* want to do that - it is a consequence of interface design.

I will explain my predicament by going through the process that led me there:

Say I have an interface with some (potentially) performance critical generic method, i.e:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    Result RelativeComputation(ISomeInterface other);
}
```

However the `ISomeInterface` itself is not a sufficiently strong restraint: I want the details that make this computation possible to be an implementation detail - I specifically do *not* want to expose the required data in the interface itself because it is *only* needed for that one method, *and* to make matters worse the required data is generic (of a type not used anywhere else in that or any related interface) so exposing it would litter additional generics into every other interface or class that makes use of `ISomeInterface`.

So to solve the above the next logical evolution of the code is:

```
interface ISomeInterface<T> where T : ISomeInterface<T>
{
    Result RelativeComputation(T other);
}
```

Now no implementation details need to be exposed, the constraint is strong, and in most cases this would be the happy ending.

However, situations can arise where `T` is fulfilled by another interface, i.e:

```
interface IOtherInterface : ISomeInterface<IOtherInterface>
{
    //... *other stuff*
}
```

Now there are issues again! :(

- Firstly, as mentioned in the beginning, this method call could end up in performance critical code, so in those cases it might be desirable to make the `other` parameter a struct. However with the code above this would inevitably be ruined by boxing.
- Secondly the constraint on `T` in `RelativeComputation(T other)` that appeared to be strong is actually too weak - unless we choose to expose implementation details again! (Either directly in `ISomeInterface` as discussed before, or in `IOtherInterface`.)

The second issue I don't really have a *good* solution for, other than making `IOtherInterface` generic and applying the Curiously Repeating Template Pattern on it too, and then add the computation method again. The result being:

```
interface IOtherInterface<T> : ISomeInterface<IOtherInterface<T>>
    where T : IOtherInterface<T>
{
    new Result RelativeComputation(T other);
    //... *other stuff*
}
```

...eventually the inheritance hierarchy would reach a concrete type and the implementation details will remain hidden.
This is admittedly not very elegant, but it is also not the real issue so I digress.

The **real issue** at hand is the "First" issue mentioned above.
At first glance it would appear easy to solve; Make the method itself generic, like so:

```
interface ISomeInterface<T> where T : ISomeInterface<T>
{
    Result RelativeComputation<T2>(T2 other) where T2 : T;
}
```

Now the parameter can be a struct and there will be no boxing anymore!
(This is true even if `T` above is an interface, e.g. `IOtherInterface`.)

Great right!
So lets just make a suitable struct, i.e. implementing `ISomeInterface` (or a more derived interface, as `IOtherInterface`) and the problem is, eeh... oh.

If you haven't already figured it out, here is what that code would look like:

```
struct MyPerformantStruct : ISomeInterface<MyPerformantStruct>
{
    Result RelativeComputation<T2>(T2 other) where T2 : MyPerformantStruct; // nope! :(
}
```

The interface requires that exact signature, but that does **not** compile!

**I'm hoping there is some way to solve this?**
(Allow structs with no boxing **and** hide as much implementation as possible!)

*To clarify I don't expect there is a way to use a struct as a generic constraint, but rather I am hoping there is another workaround, like a clever design improvement (and / or hack).*

### EDIT:

Current answers and comments have given me insight into some additional information that is of relevance:

- The interface and the implementing type can reside in different assemblies. (The interface is in a library.)
- I'm not saying it *has* to be a struct, I'm saying it *should be possible* to use either a class or a struct (without boxing).
- The "implementation details" I'm referring to is some value type (possibly more than one). The method in question is a `bool IsLessThan(...)` type of method, something I can't seem to evaluate without boxing, unboxing and runtime-checks (no thanks!) - *or* without knowing implementation details about the underlying type and exposing those in the interface, thus locking the implementation and defeating the whole point of the abstraction - *or* restricting it on the interface level, which has other issues mentioned above - *or* also restricting it on the method level, which is what I wanted to do above, but as it turns out that explicitly prevents `T` from being a struct.
- (I prefer to stay on .net 3.5 but this is not critical.)
- My problem description is long and it isn't instantly obvious why generics is required on both the interface and the method, so I will provide a code example and illustrate why it doesn't compile (or would require runtime casting):

This code illustrates the need to constrain to the actual type:

```
interface IExample
{
    bool IsLessThan<T>(T other) where T : IExample;
}

class ExampleClass : IExample
{
    short someValue;
    public bool IsLessThan<T>(T other) where T : IExample
    {
        return this.someValue < other.???; // <-- what now?
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't help you here, but it's worth noting there's a good reason a struct can't be a generic constraint -- by definition, it's not useful, as you can't inherit from a struct. There is no T2 that would satisfy the constraint in the first place.

Comment: C# already has a feature to realize "a struct with no boxing that hides implementation": a class. Why do you think structs will give you a performance benefit?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I am well aware. I said so myself twice. I repeat, it is a consequence of other design, not something I _want_ to do per see,

Comment: @JeroenMostert stack vs heap. The pains and complications game programmers sometimes goes through to _remove_ a perfectly working class from the code and replace it with a struct...

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't want boxing, you can pretty much forget about interfaces. In general, the use of structs for performance has to be isolated to particular hairy bits, and those hairy bits aren't going to have anything in the way of nice O-O design.

Comment: That is often true... But I haven't given up on this one yet. This is at the very core so I really want it to be nice. It's 2am here, but I have one more idea I'm going to try tomorrow. (It requires .net 4.0 though and I would have preferred to target .net 3.5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that what I like to do can not be done.
Something has to give, and in this case it will simply be `IOtherInterface`.
Simply put, if one wishes to use a struct and not suffer any boxing `T` in `ISomeInterface` *has* to be the struct itself (with the method no longer having its own generics).

Any workaround I can think of would absolutely cost more than a simple boxing instruction.

So I'm closing this as not doable.
Thanks for your replies people.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should ask a question about the actual problem you're solving. It's very hard to understand what you're trying to do, and why you're trying to do it, if you use only examples. Perhaps you're approaching the problem wrong, or is there a better solution to your *actual* problem. There are a myriad of design patterns that solve many problems.

It looks like you're doing micro-optimizations. Have you measured the code in question? Have you found the bottleneck to be really there?

You'd like code that looks like this:

```
struct MyPerformantStruct : ISomeInterface<MyPerformantStruct>
{
    Result RelativeComputation<T2>(T2 other) where T2 : MyPerformantStruct;
}
```

But... *why*? If `MyPerformantStruct` is a struct, then, *by definition*, there is no class or struct whatsoever that can inherit from it. The only type that could ever satisfy `T2` is... `MyPerformantStruct`. So why not use that directly?

```
interface ISomeInterface<T>
    where T : struct
{
    Result RelativeComputation(T other);
}

struct MyPerformantStruct : ISomeInterface<MyPerformantStruct>
{
    Result RelativeComputation(MyPerformantStruct other);
}
```

Is there a reason `T` is a generic parameter on the type instead of on the member?

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    Result RelativeComputation<T>(T other)
        where T : struct;
}

struct MyPerformantStruct : ISomeInterface
{
    Result RelativeComputation<MyPerformantStruct>(MyPerformantStruct other);
}
```

Would your code not work with things other than structs? Seems unlikely to me, so then you could drop the `struct` constraint. You'd still get the benefits of unboxed structs when `T` is a struct.

```
interface ISomeInterface
{
    Result RelativeComputation<T>(T other);
}

struct MyPerformantStruct : ISomeInterface
{
    Result RelativeComputation<MyPerformantStruct>(MyPerformantStruct other);
}
```

And are you sure you can deal with this struct without boxing it, ever? If not, you might as well just abstract over the type and ask for the struct's interface, or `object` if you really want to. I'm guessing that the only reason you're working with structs is performance. This is the wrong approach. Structs should represent immutable *values*, such as a date/time pair or a percentage. Structs aren't boxless collections of mutable fields that you use for performance reasons. And you'll run into issues later on if you try to use them as such.

Comment: You are missing a lot of points. I said potential performance requirement. It could be called millions of times per second on a cluster (this will actually happen). Or maybe only a few times per second (this might happen in a related project). It is part of a library though, so performance testing is speculative (in theory), which brings me to the next thing:  I never said it **will be** a struct. I said it **can be** a struct. Also if you constrain it directly to the struct you are forcing a specific implementation, and in some scenarios a class might be more useful or required..... <cont...>

Comment: <cont...> On the other hand if you constrain it directly as the interface you must expose implementation somewhere. Specifically we are talking about exposing valuetypes because these are abstractions that depend on numerical values. These abstraction allowing the consumer to choose best implementation based on precision, performance, memory, value-range and target hardware requirements. I don't think such decisions / limitations belongs in the lib. (It will supply a default implementation though.)

Comment: As for your first concern, that is very much possible. I am trying to keep the question as general as possible, perhaps too general. I did add a bit more information.... hopefully its of use?

Answer (score 2):

There are two different problems in your question: struct constraints in generic type definitions with regards to boxing, and how to hide implementation details inside an assembly.

As you pointed out, you cannot set a generic type parameter to be of an explicit `struct` type. You can, however, enforce a generic type parameter `T` to both be a `struct` and implement a specific interface:

```
interface ISomeInterface<T> where T : struct, ISomeInterface<T>
{
    Result RelativeComputation(T other);
}
```

Now about boxing: generics are meant to prevent boxing from happening (see [Benefits of Generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b5bx6xee(v=vs.110).aspx)). Consider the following program:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    int GetValue();
}

public struct SomeStruct : ISomeInterface
{
    public int GetValue() { return 42; }
}

public interface ISomeOtherInterface1<T> where T : ISomeInterface
{
    int ComputeStuff(T other);
}

public interface ISomeOtherInterface2<T> where T : struct, ISomeInterface
{
    int ComputeStuff(T other);
}

class ClassImplementingInterface1<T> : ISomeOtherInterface1<T> where T : ISomeInterface
{
    public int ComputeStuff(T other) { return other.GetValue(); }
}

class ClassImplementingInterface2<T> : ISomeOtherInterface2<T> where T : struct, ISomeInterface
{
    public int ComputeStuff(T other) { return other.GetValue(); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var value = new SomeStruct();
        var obj1 = new ClassImplementingInterface1<SomeStruct>();
        var obj2 = new ClassImplementingInterface2<SomeStruct>();
        var obj3 = new ClassImplementingInterface1<ISomeInterface>();
        var result1 = obj1.ComputeStuff(value);
        var result2 = obj2.ComputeStuff(value);
        var result3 = obj3.ComputeStuff(value);
    }
}
```

In this exemple I have an interface that is implemented by a struct, and two different generic interfaces: the second one enforces its generic type parameter to be a struct where the first doesn't. In the `Main` method you see 3 different ways of using those classes. If you look at the assembly code produced by the last 3 lines of code in the `Disassembly` window in Visual Studio, you will see that the code for the first two calls are identical: no boxing occurs. The assembly code of those two `ComputeStuff` methods are also identical, because both the code and the effective type parameters are identical. Only the last one causes boxing to happen because it uses the `ISomeInterface` type as the effective type parameter, and interface types are reference types in the CLR world so any value type passed will indeed be boxed.

---

About hiding implementation details, it seems unclear to me what you are trying to hide to external code exactly, but maybe what you are missing is that it is possible for public types to implement internal interfaces, if they implement them explicitly:

```
internal struct PrivateData { ... }

internal interface IMyInterface
{
    Result SomePrivateComputation(PrivateData data);
}

public class MyPublicClass : IMyInterface
{
    Result IMyInterface.SomePrivateComputation(PrivateData data)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then your code in its assembly (and friend assemblies specified by any [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) will be able to do the following:

```
MyPublicClass myObj;
...
((IMyInterface)myObj).SomePrivateComputation(myData); // No boxing here, no virtual call either: the compiler knows which method to invoke on MyPublicClass.
```

Comment: I actually didn't know explicit implementation allows internal interfaces on public types. Unfortunately that does not help in my case, because `ISomeInterface` is in a library, and the point is exactly to allow the consumer of that library to roll its own type (if the included default implementation isn't good enough). Neither do I want to force it to be a struct, rather I don't want to force it to be a class (or force it to be boxed) - I want both options to be available and let the consumer choose. As for what I'm hiding / abstracting away: numerical valuetypes.

Comment: Things that want to benefit from `using` must implement `IDisposable`.  Perhaps it is a necessary and fairly reasonable restriction that things that will benefit from your library must implement `ISomeInterfaceYourLibraryDefines`, even if it is an empty interface declaration.

Comment: @EricJ. The interface isn't empty, I just want to keep certain things out of it, so yes, they indeed must implement it.